# JSP file does not load in browser - whitelabel error page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to write a simple web MVC application using spring boot.  However, when I run the application in IntelliJ, I keep getting the default whitelabel error page.

My main class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "test");
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.6'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit'
}
```

This is my application.properites file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

My jsp file is here: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

and looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">
           <h1>Message: ${message}</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering what I am missing here? Is there something I need to add/change in my gradle file? Am I missing some sort of configuration beans? When I try the annotation @RestController, I do not get a whitelabel error page, but I do not get the jsp file. Instead I simply get "welcome", as returned by the method in my MainController. As I understand it, @RestController does not allow for view, but @Controller does. However, I am unable to get the jsp to be rendered, even when I do use @Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think missing starter-tomcat might be problem.
Add this to your gradle.

```
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
```

Comment: You are probably right that I needed that. However, I was still getting the same error after adding this and running locally from IntelliJ. However, I was able to get the application to run as expected when using this command from the command prompt: gradle bootRun. I did a similar project in maven with same results, but got it to run using the mvn spring-boot:run command. I don't know why. Perhaps I am using IntelliJ wrong (I am more familiar with Eclipse), or I need to update IntelliJ.